# pip install pandas error

Tags: python, pandas, pip

Hi all i typed `pip install pandas` but i kept getting this error.

```
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\use
rs\\huihui\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_HuiHui\\pandas\\setup.py';exec(compi
le(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __fil
e__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\huihui\appdata\local\temp\pip-ecokb6-re
cord\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed wit
h error code 1 in c:\users\huihui\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_HuiHui\pandas
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\HuiHui\pip\pip.log
```

can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Have you followed the advice and had a look at `C:\Users\HuiHui\pip\pip.log`?

Comment: yeah but i dont get it... let me edit it in...

Comment: May I recommend installing [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) for pandas instead?

Answer (score 2):

`pip` will try to install from source and I deduce from the `C:` that you are on windows - as such you probably don't have the compiler(s) needed to build pandas.  You should download install the appropriate windows installer from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas instead.